# Question about Abstract Classes when classes are nested

Tags: java, class, abstract

So let's say `ClassB` is a class defined inside `ClassA` (Nested Classes), my question is, if `ClassB` is declared `abstract` as it contains abstract Methods, would ClassA also have to be declared `Abstract` ?

Comment: No, A wouldn't have to. Even if they shared an inheritance relationship, `ClassA` as a parent of `ClassB` would still not have to abstract because the child is.

Comment: Why not to check this yourself up? why not to open your IDE, write some little code and just check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it doesn't. It doesn't matter whether the outer or parent class is `abstract`, there is no rule in Java enforcing a class being `abstract`.

An example:

```
class classA {
    abstract class classB {      // can also be static
        abstract void foo();
    }
}
```

On the other hand, it's a bit different with the methods: `abstract` methods *must be* placed only inside the `abstract` classes or interfaces (implicitely abstract).

Answer (score 1):

No.  The methods of each class are its own.  A class does not own the methods of other classes (or interfaces!) nested within, and containing a nested abstract class or a nested interface does not require the container class to be abstract.